# Having an issue creating a separate quantile column based on a condition

Tags: pandas

I am trying to create a new column that contains quantile information. The one condition I have for this new column is that I only need to produce a quantile value for rows where it equals a certain value from another column. I thought the code below would filter the data to the specific value ("Below") and apply the quantile to only those records but I'm getting the quantile data for all rows.

```
rsh_df['pcf_q'] = rsh_df.loc[rsh_df['ind_comp'] == "Below", 'pcf'].quantile(0.05)
```

[Image of the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuHFr.png)

How can I adjust the code to explicitly apply quantiles to a certain tag?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the values, to the rows where the condition is met. Try:

```
rsh_df.loc[rsh_df['ind_comp'] == "Below", 'pcf_q'] = (
    rsh_df
    .loc[rsh_df['ind_comp'] == "Below", 'pcf']
    .quantile(0.05)
)
```

Comment: Wow, that worked! Thank you very much. So I guess with my code it wasn't explicit at all to assign the quantile value to those specific rows?

Comment: Right, you were creating a column with the same value for every row.